# Method to check if User comes Closer to Bluetooth Low Energy Device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am searching for a method to check the distance between an User and a Bluetooth Low Energy device. I know the RSSI Signal is not a good solution for this but is there an example for checking if the User Comes closer to the Device?

What I did so far is just this:

```
if (bleDeviceMapKey != null) {
    deviceTest1 = bleDeviceMapKey.deviceAddress;
    if (bleDeviceMap.get(deviceTest1).rssi > -60) {
        startNewActivity(getApplicationContext(), ConnectedActivity.class);
        scanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
    }
```

So if the RSSI is better then -60 start a new Activity and connect to it. But what I want is a method which check if the User is moving towards the target.

Comment: then remember previous RSSI and compare it to current RSSI. If current is higher - user moving towards

Comment: can you show me this with sample code?

Comment: it is too simple and too dependant on your code. Just store the `bleDeviceMap.get(deviceTest1).rssi` value in some variable each time you get the RSSI, and before doing that check if current RSSI is higher than previous (saved)

Comment: You need at least some filtering, because the rssi tends to fluctuate, even when both devices don't move.

Comment: what i did now is this: `if (bleDeviceMapKey != null) {
                        int rssi1 = bleDeviceMap.get(deviceTest1).rssi;
                        while ( rssi1 > bleDeviceMap.get(deviceTest1).rssi) {
                            rssi1 = bleDeviceMap.get(deviceTest1).rssi;
                            if (rssi1 == -40){
                                startNewActivity(getApplicationContext(),ConnectedActivity.class);
                                scanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
                            }
                        }`

Comment: You need to check the rssi continuasly and keep an average